# Two locks on message? Encryption?

Tags: encryption, locking

I need to secure a database where data comes from different clients at a time. To maintain the integrity in mid-way network the message needs to be encrypted in some way. If database server knows the encryption method, then it decrypts and stores the data. Which is not ok in this case as if some breach happens then the message might be leaked in mid-way network.

So, need some algorithm like SSH. Client sends data locked, database server locks the message and resends it. The client then unlocks the data and finally database server has the message with it's locking system which can be removed and the data can be read.

I don't care if the database server is breached. All I want is to maintain integrity of message while travelling through the network.

Any suggestions or references to achieve this will be appreciated.

Comment: You seem to need a *transport protocol*. TLS is a one such a protocol and SSH can be thought of as another, indeed. Otherwise, this question is too vague to be answered, which is a shame because otherwise you could ask it on [security.se] where it would be on topic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it doesn't contain any programming related question.